# How can i find the coordinates of a Picturebox stored within a 2D array, on click

Tags: vb.net

I have a grid of pictureboxes stored within a 2D array and i need to retrieve the coordinates within the array of each picturebox when clicked on.

The pictureboxes are stored like this:

```
    Grid(1, 1) = PictureBox1
    Grid(2, 2) = PictureBox2
    Grid(2, 4) = PictureBox3
    Grid(3, 1) = PictureBox4
    Grid(4, 2) = PictureBox5
    Grid(5, 1) = PictureBox6
    Grid(7, 1) = PictureBox7
    Grid(6, 2) = PictureBox8
    Grid(9, 1) = PictureBox9
    Grid(10, 2) = PictureBox10
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to reach your wanted result?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, i tried to declare x and y to variables however i couldn't figure out how i could get x and y to store in those variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When what is clicked?

You can get location with this for example:

```
Dim test = Grid(1, 1).Location 'picturebox1.location
Dim test2 = "x location is: " & test.X & ", y location is: " & test.Y
```

or directly with

```
Dim test3 = Grid(1, 1).Location.x 'or y
```

Edit:

```
 For y = 0 To Grid.GetLength(0)-1 'row count
        For x = 0 To Grid.GetLength(1)-1 'column count
            If Grid(y, x) IsNot Nothing Then
                If Grid(y, x).name = sender.name Then
                    Dim test = String.Format("y is: {0}, x is: {1}", y, x)
                    GoTo exit_for
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
exit_for:
```

Comment: When the picturebox itself is clicked i want it to return that picturebox's location within the 2d array

Comment: Ahh, so you want, for example (1,1)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what i'm after

Comment: Well there are multiple way, the "best" solution depends on your needs.
I would simply loop over it to find what I need, 2 lines and it's done.

Comment: I'm using it as a gameboard so i need to be able to compare it to the other values stored within the array to see if a move is legal

Comment: Edited a bit, forgot to exit loop when found, you could either use goto or try then end try within loop or double exit for but that takes more lines :)

Comment: When i tried to test it it said that  "If Grid(y, x).Name = sender.name Then" was not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Ahh yes, I see. You have empty cells in array, we should skip those.